# Mixed Model Ancova

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, sample-size

For a research project, I want to compute a Mixed-Design ANCOVA, i.e., a repeated measures analysis with one within-subjects factor (3 points of measurement) + one between-subjects factor (2 groups) + three covariates.
Does anyone know how to do sample size calculations, when I expect a high effect size (F = .30), in an a priori power analysis in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect size is not clearly defined here. In addition, you are testing multiple hypotheses, it's not clear which specific hypothesis you are talking  about when you say 'high effect size.' There are assumptions that you need to make (or check for), such as sphericity, violation of sphericity means that you have less power (for some tests).

Typically, the best way to answer these questions is through simulation - that makes you think hard about all of the parameters, and examine their effects on the effect size / power. (In addition, it's also possible to power this sort of model using structural equation models: https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-3-27 ).